How to increase speed when itererating over all controls of a window using UIA?
Whats the best practice or options to speed up the search when you are iterating the entire control list of a window?
I have tried creating a property condition to find only the items that are not empty as:
pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, CComVariant(L""), &pNameNotEmptyCondition);

but it didnt make any different on the time when compared to not using it.
I'm interested on just the name property, there's something else i could try instead of caching, to increase the search speed?
#include <windows.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

inline void uiaElements2(CComPtr<IUIAutomation> pAutomation, CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pRootElement, std::set<std::wstring>& elementsList, int parsedCount = 0)
{
    // Create a condition for non-empty names
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> pNameNotEmptyCondition;
    pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, CComVariant(L""), &pNameNotEmptyCondition);
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> pNameNotEmptyNotCondition;
    pAutomation->CreateNotCondition(pNameNotEmptyCondition, &pNameNotEmptyNotCondition);

    std::function<void(CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement>)> processElement = [&](CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pCurrentElement)
    {
        parsedCount++;
        if (parsedCount > 2000)
            return;

        BSTR bstrName;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pCurrentElement->get_CurrentName(&bstrName)) && bstrName)
        {
            elementsList.insert(bstrName);
            SysFreeString(bstrName);
        }

        CComPtr<IUIAutomationElementArray> pChildren;
        pCurrentElement->FindAll(TreeScope_Children, pNameNotEmptyNotCondition, &pChildren);
        if (!pChildren)
            return;

        int childCount;
        pChildren->get_Length(&childCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pChild;
            pChildren->GetElement(i, &pChild);
            if (pChild)
                processElement(pChild);
        }
    };

    // Start processing from the root element
    processElement(pRootElement);
}

inline void uiaElements(CComPtr<IUIAutomation> pAutomation, CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pRootElement, std::set<std::wstring>& elementsList, int parsedCount = 0)
{
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> pTrueCondition;
    pAutomation->CreateTrueCondition(&pTrueCondition);
    std::function<void(CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement>)> processElement = [&](CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pCurrentElement)
    {
        parsedCount++;
        if (parsedCount > 2000)
            return;
        BSTR bstrName;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pCurrentElement->get_CurrentName(&bstrName)) && bstrName)
        {
            elementsList.insert(bstrName);
            SysFreeString(bstrName);
        }
        CComPtr<IUIAutomationElementArray> pChildren;
        pCurrentElement->FindAll(TreeScope_Children, pTrueCondition, &pChildren);
        if (!pChildren)
            return;
        int childCount;
        pChildren->get_Length(&childCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pChild;
            pChildren->GetElement(i, &pChild);
            if (pChild)
                processElement(pChild);
        }
    };
    // Start processing from the root element
    processElement(pRootElement);
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, ...);
    CComPtr<IUIAutomation> pAutomation;
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> pRootElement;
    std::set<std::wstring> elementList;
    std::set<std::wstring> elementList2;

    if (SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, (void**)&pAutomation)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            HRESULT hr = pAutomation->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pRootElement);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pRootElement)
            {
                uiaElements(pAutomation, pRootElement, elementList);
                uiaElements2(pAutomation, pRootElement, elementList2);
                break;
            }
            else
                std::wcout << L"Failed: " << hr << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "CoCreateInstance failed" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Unconditionnaly traversing the whole UI tree will always be long, and in fact it's not even guaranteed to work, as UI may freeze waiting for an end-user action, depending on the app context, etc. You should only work on conditions, on automationId, control type, name, etc.

@SimonMourier this is what im trying to understand, if its possible to get only the name at once instead of iterating everything.

Just create a condition on the name you search and call FindAll(TreeScope_Descendants...)
